# unserialize() error in report forms

Tags: civireport, upgrade

I've just upgraded a test system running under Joomla to 5.5.0.  Looking at certain reports gives this error:

Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 166 of 1907 bytes in ...\administrator\components\com_civicrm\civicrm\CRM\Report\Form.php on line 611

Comment: Try saving the report again and i believe you wont see that again.

Comment: Sorry, @PradeepNayak, but all I get when I try View Results again is a blank screen with a # in the top-left corner.  I'll try updating to 5.5.3.